# Bootstrap with five images with same row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I m expecting like this image [Link](http://s4.postimg.org/f31qjpq5p/untitled.png)

In the image there 5 images and link to dotted images..

May i know, How to display with using bootstrap classes.

I just confused, can anyone help me to fix this?

Thanks,

Here is the code by using table tag:

```
<td class="tdbodycontent" id="workDemo">
                <div class="wrapper" style="height:340px;">
                    <table class="tblhomecontent dotted" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td colspan="5">
                                <div class="boxtitle">
                                    How it works</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="box5col">
                                <div class="marker_1 center">
                                </div>
                                <p class="markerContent">
                                    Sign Up for free</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="box5col">
                                <div class="marker_2 center">
                                </div>
                                <p class="markerContent">
                                    Select the<br>
                                    neighborhoods<br>
                                    you want to follow</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="box5col">
                                <div class="marker_3 center">
                                </div>
                                <p class="markerContent">
                                    Invite friends and<br>
                                    family to join</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="box5col">
                                <div class="marker_4 center">
                                </div>
                                <p class="markerContent">
                                    Receive important<br>
                                    alerts and information<br>
                                    from trusted sources</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="box5col">
                                <div class="marker_5 center">
                                </div>
                                <p class="markerContent">
                                    Share information<br>
                                    with friends<br>
                                    securely</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </div>
            </td>
```

I need to convert in bootstrap, Here is the image link [dotted](http://s22.postimg.org/53ci53xht/dotted.png) , [step-1](http://s22.postimg.org/pq17qfgwd/step_1.png) , [step-2](http://s22.postimg.org/5u58avzv1/step_2.png) , [step-3](http://s22.postimg.org/58g9es4st/step_3.png) , [step-4](http://s22.postimg.org/576bld2z1/step_4.png) , [step-5](http://s22.postimg.org/g9bejsx1p/step_5.png)

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I m using div class container and i referred columns in bootstrap.. it is limited with 12 columns and here in my page there are 5 sections.. so i just confused, how to start..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on top of `anu g prem`'s solution, and adding something for the dotted lines, plus a bit of explanations.

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/u8Ldc6no/7/)

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row steps">
    <hr class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" />

    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1"><img src="http://s22.postimg.org/pq17qfgwd/step_1.png" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="http://s22.postimg.org/5u58avzv1/step_2.png" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="http://s22.postimg.org/58g9es4st/step_3.png" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="http://s22.postimg.org/576bld2z1/step_4.png" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="http://s22.postimg.org/g9bejsx1p/step_5.png" class="img-responsive"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.steps {
    position: relative;
}

.steps hr {
    /* Use the 3 lines below to use a dotted line image file as background of the <hr> */
    border: none;
    background: transparent url('http://s22.postimg.org/53ci53xht/dotted.png') no-repeat center center;
    height: 2px;
    /* Use the line below instead to style the <hr> with a border */
    /*border-top: 1px dashed gray;*/

    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}

.steps .img-responsive {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You'll notice I did not use your dotted line, and instead used an `<hr>`, and styled its `border-top` with a dashed line. (Edit: but op **wants** to use the image he provided, see comments.)

To answer your question regarding the number of columns (10 vs Bootstrap grid's 12), you need to understand that you don't always have to fill all the twelve columns. Here, we're using 2 columns per image, plus a first column as offset, and you get your five images, centered, with one offset column on the left, and an empty column on the right, and it's fine!

Note that I used `img-responsive` class to ensure your images never grow too big, outside of their 2 columns, and that I used `xs` (meaning "extra small") in the class `col-xs-2`, which means all device screen sizes will get the five images on the same line (and resized to fit), which might not be want you want for smaller devices...

Comment: Can you please explain why you **need** to use the dotted line image? Are you at least allowed to edit it to render it more usable (remove the white space on the left, that prevents the image to be repeated as a background). Did you check my [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/u8Ldc6no/5/)? The line is pretty similar to your image, and I'm sure that with a bit more work, you could adjust the thickness and color to be exactly the same.

Comment: Not any reason.. I just need to use dotted image, which is links to those 5 images by using bootstrap.. thanks

Comment: @saina You're gonna have to give more details, because this doesn't really make sense to me... Anyway, I edited my post above with a solution that allows you to use a dotted line image file instead of pure CSS border styling. How is that?

Comment: @saina No, this is entirely another question, and we should not discuss it here. You should post another question to ask it, please. By the way, if you consider the solution I provided above solves your problem, it would be really nice to accept it.

Comment: when i resize the window, the responsive view is not working .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88767/discussion-between-saina-and-david-stosik).

Answer (score 2):

This may work for you.
or you need to write a custom media css style to achieve this.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1"><img src="images/sample.jpg"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><img src="images/sample.jpg"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><img src="images/sample.jpg"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><img src="images/sample.jpg"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><img src="images/sample.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: may i know how to connect with dotted image..? thanks